# csplit produces too few output files, expecting more

Tags: regex, split

I have a file that contains several lines like these:

```
1291126929200 started 88 videolist15.txt 4 Good 4
1291126929250 59.875 29.0 29.580243595150186 43.016096916037604
1291126929296 59.921 29.0 29.52749417740926 42.78632483544682
1291126929359 59.984 29.0 29.479540161281143 42.56031951027556
1291126929437 60.046 50.0 31.345036510255586 42.682281485516945
1291126932859 started 88 videolist15.txt 5 Good 4
```

I want to split the files for every line that contains `started` (or `videolist`, does not matter).

The following command only produces 2 output files:

```
$ csplit -k input.txt /started/
```

However I expect a lot more, as can be seen in:

```
$ grep -i started input.txt |wc -l
$ 146
```

What would be the correct `csplit` command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `{*}` at the end:

```
$ csplit -k input.txt /started/ {*}
```

The man page says:

```
{*}    repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible.
```

Note that some shells may interpret this as a special pattern. In that case, quote it with `"{*}"`.

Also, make sure you use the GNU version of `csplit`, which is available under macOS with `brew install coreutils`.

Demo:

```
$ cat file
1
foo
2
foo
3
foo
$ csplit -k file /foo/ {*}
2
6
6
4
$ ls -tr xx*             
xx03  xx02  xx01  xx00
$ csplit --version
csplit (GNU coreutils) 7.4
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me: `csplit: *}: bad repetition count`. It worked with an arbitrary number, though. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @slhck: Works fine for me. I've added a demo run. I'll see if this is version problem.

Comment: I see. I have the BSD version bundled with OS X which doesn't even have a `--version` switch.

Comment: @slhck `{*}` is a convenient GNU extensions. Other `csplit` implementations require an explicit repetition count. Sometimes you can get away with a very large number (`{999999999}`), other times you need a [first pass with `grep`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46325/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-text-files/46330#46330).

Comment: @slhck On OSX {*} is not supported, but you can use homebrew (`brew install coreutils`) to get the gnu versions of the popular command line tools. You'll access them by prefixing a 'g' to the command name, like `gcsplit` in this case.

Comment: On zsh, I needed to change `{*}` to `"{*}"` to circumvent a failed shell expansion attempt.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Open Group specifications the [csplit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/csplit.html) command accepts [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

Basic REGEXPs are a limited subset of full regex implementations. They support literal characters, asterisk (*), dot (.), character classes ([0-9]) and anchors (^,$). They **don't** support one-or-more (+) or alternation (a|b).

Comment: This has no relevance to the actual question I asked, which was answered years ago.

Comment: @slhck Might this information help someone else who stumbled onto this question while trying to use csplit in their own situation?

Comment: This is *very* general info though that would of course be nice to have *in addition* to an actual answer to the question. As it stands, this would better be suited as a comment.