# Does csplit on OS X not recognise '$' as end-of-line character?

Tags: macos, unix

(I'm using Mac OS X, and this question might be specific to that variant of Unix)

I'm trying to split a file using `csplit` with a regular expression. It consists of various articles merged into one single long text file. Each article ends with "All Rights Reserved". This is at the end of the line: `grep Reserved$` finds them all. Only, `csplit` claims there is no match.

`csplit filename /Reserved$/`

yields

`csplit: Reserved$: no match`

which is a clear and obvious lie. If I leave out the `$`, it works; but I want to be sure that I don't get any stray occurrences of 'Reserved' in the middle of the text. I tried a different word with the beginning-of-line character `^`, and that seems to work. Other words (which do occur at the end of a line in the data) also do not match when used (eg `and$`).

Is this a known bug with OS X?

[Update: I made sure it's not a DOS/Unix line end character issue by removing all carriage return characters]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have downloaded the source code of csplit from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-84/csplit/csplit.c and tested this in the debugger.

The pattern is compiled with

```
if (regcomp(&cre, re, REG_BASIC|REG_NOSUB) != 0)
    errx(1, "%s: bad regular expression", re);
```

and the lines are matched with

```
/* Read and output lines until we get a match. */
first = 1;
while ((p = csplit_getline()) != NULL) {
    if (fputs(p, ofp) == EOF)
        break;
    if (!first && regexec(&cre, p, 0, NULL, 0) == 0)
        break;
    first = 0;
}
```

The problem is now that the lines returned by `csplit_getline()` still have a trailing newline character `\n`. Therefore "Reserved" are not the last characters in the string and the pattern "Reserved$" does not match.

After a quick-and-dirty insertion of

```
    p[strlen(p)-1] = 0;
```

to remove the trailing newline from the input string the "Reserved$" pattern worked as expected.

There seem to be more problems with csplit in Mac OS X, see the remarks to the answer of [Looking for correct Regular Expression for csplit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323703/looking-for-correct-regular-expression-for-csplit) (the repetition count `{*}` does also not work).

*Remark:* You can match "Reserved" at the end of the line with the following trick:

```
csplit filename /Reserved<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-J>/
```

where you actually use the Control keys to enter a newline character on the command line.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `split filename /Reserved.$/` which also works!

Comment: @OliverMason: I see, that is also a good solution/workaround (the dot matches the newline character).