# Using regex to tell csplit where to split the file

Tags: regex, bash, bsd, csplit

I have a large text file with content set up like this:

```
---
title: Lorim Ipsum Dolar
---
Lorim ipsum content
---
title: Excelvier whatever 
---
Lorim ipsum content goes here.
```

I'm trying to split up this file into individual files using `csplit`.

The individual files would have content formatted like this:

```
---
title: Lorim Ipsum Dolar
---
Lorim ipsum content
```

I was hoping to be able to regex the ---, newline & title like so `---\ntitle`

But I'm not able to select it with…

```
csplit -k products.txt '/---[^\n]title/' {99}
```

I've tried lots of variations to no avail. I keeping getting "no match".

Comment: I don't know about `csplit`, but have you tried `/---[\r\n]+title/` ? (`[^ ...]` is a negated class and sometimes, there are carriage returns together with newlines).

Answer (score 7):

You could use a regular expression that matches until the end of the line (`$`)

What do you think about:

```
csplit -k products.txt '/^title:/' {99}
```

Comment: I was hoping that it could do a multi-line deal, but this does work.

Answer (score 6):

csplit reads the input file one line at a time and applies the regex to each line. It is therefore not possible to match a regex across multiple lines.

One way around this is to massage the input file first, replacing `---\ntitle:` with a single line pattern that csplit can match. For example, using sed:

```
sed 'N;s/---\ntitle: /===\n' products.txt | csplit -k - '/===/' {*}
sed 'N;s/===\n/---\ntitle: /' -i xx*
```

This replaces `---\ntitle:` with a single line `===`, then has csplit split when it sees that pattern. Passing `-` as a file name tells csplit to read from stdin. The second sed command reverses the change.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `{*}` instead of `{99}` to fix `match not found` problem.

Comment: I believe the `{99}` just tells `csplit` how many time to repeat the process. Anyway, in my version of BSD `{*}` would not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323703/looking-for-correct-regular-expression-for-csplit#comment-25322197

Comment: @PhilipMeissner This is very interesting. Under debian csplit will always try to find specified number of matches, if it cannot find 99 matches, then an error will be thrown. ``csplit --version`` says ``csplit (GNU coreutils) 8.21``

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
csplit -z products.txt '/^title/-1' '{*}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was don't use `csplit`, use `awk`.

```
awk '
/^title:/ {++count; file="file"count".txt"; print file}
file {print line > file}
{line=$0}
' products.txt
```

The first command declares a new file when `title:` is encoutered. The second command writes the *preceding* line to `file` if `file` has been declared. The third command assigns the current line to a variable.