# How do I separately print lines matching same pattern using grep

Tags: awk, grep

Suppose I have a file in which there are lines matching same pattern but under different blocks how to write them in a separate file using grep/awk 
for example:

```
$ cat file.txt
spin 1 
voltage current
spin 2
voltage current
$
```

I want to write spin 1 voltage current in a separate file "spi1.dat" and spin 2 voltage current in a separate file. How to I do this using grep/awk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regex to tell csplit where to split the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364411/using-regex-to-tell-csplit-where-to-split-the-file)

Comment: Do you want to look for lines that start with "spin" and print everything after them into one file, or look for lines that start with "voltage" and print them to a file named based on the last line that didn't start with voltage or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite clear but here's an `awk` approach:

```
awk '/^spin/{spin=$0;idx=$NF;getline;print spin" "$0 >"spin"idx".dat"}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea with awk but you can do a somewhat similar thing with split:

```
split -d -l 2 file.txt spi.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

In grep -A option is used to  Print lines of trailing context after matching.

```
  grep 'spin 1' -A1  file.txt spi1.dat
```