# CSplit regexp not working

Tags: regex, bash, csplit

I have the following file content

```
testing with
---- ----
get footer
```

I want to split it with the ---- ---- . There may be some other content between the '----'. I am using the following, but it keeps telling that match not found.

```
csplit -f instruction $FILE /^[-]{4}[\s\S]*[-]{4}$/
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18364586/3832970, it might help. Also, [csplit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/csplit.html) accepts a BRE regex only, thus, you need something like `-\{4}.*-\{4}`. In POSIX regex, a dot matches any char incl. a newline, you do not need the `[\s\S]` like hacks.

Comment: The Perl regex extensions such as `\s` and `\S` should not be expected to exist in most regex dialects.  It's not clear what you expect `[\s\S]` to match anyway -- if it worked, it would be synonymous to `.` (any character) as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you sure there is no trailing whitespace in the delimiting line?