# How to split a text file based on the first column value of a multicolumn text

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Hi I have a text file with two columns. I want to split it by matching a block of lines and put them into a new file. I have the following styles

0                           9.4721 
3.30**1020**1        2.65397 
3.9081     3.05973 
**1020**                      3.0597
0                           9.4721 
3.30**1020**1        2.65397 
3.9081     3.05973 
**1020**                      3.0597

I want to split the file from 0 to **1020** but when I am using sed or awk it is matching the pattern and split them into four files. I want the split like this:
**File 1**
0                           9.4721 
3.30**1020**1        2.65397 
3.9081     3.05973 
**1020**                      3.0597
**File2**
0                           9.4721 
3.30**1020**1        2.65397 
3.9081     3.05973 
**1020**                      3.0597

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve your problem your self and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input, output, and code so we can copy/paste to test with it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a sed/grep/awk answer, but perhaps this will solve your problem:

```
csplit --digits=1  --quiet --prefix=file example_file.txt "/^1020/+1" "{*}"

cat file0
#0 9.4721
#3.3010201 2.65397
#3.9081 3.05973
#1020 3.0597

cat file1
#0 9.4721
#3.3010201 2.65397
#3.9081 3.05973
#1020 3.0597
```

Further info: [csplit man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html)

Similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323899/12957340

Comment: N.B. csplit numbers the files from zero and that this will create an empty file `file2`, the same result can be effected by `csplit -sn1 -f file file '/^0 /' '{*}'` which will produce the empty file in `file0` or the empty file can be eluded using a `-z` option.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` version

```
$ awk '$1==0{f=1; c++} f{print > ("file"c)} $1==1020{f=0}' file
```

**Explanation**

`$1==0{f=1; c++}` to mark the beginning of the block, set a flag and increment the file counter (initial value is zero).

`f{print > ("file"c)}` if the flag is set, print the current line to the file (which has the counter suffix).

`$1==1020{f=0}` mark the end of the block, reset the flag so that printing lines will cease until the next block starts.

Assuming space delimited values, it compares the literal match not a regex match on the first field.

If you have too many files generated this might fail because of open files.  If that's the case you may need to add `close("file"c)` in the block end marker statement (next to `f=0`}.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It works! It would be great if you have some time to explaining your comments.